# LPT Sound Interface

Tags: usb, user-interface, emulator, dosbox, lpt

I am wanting to run two ZX Spectrum (a home computer that was popular during the '80s & '90s) emulator programs (one called Z80 by Gerton Lunter and another called Warajevo) in the "ykhowong" version of DOSBox. The eumulator programs communicate through an interface box that attaches to the LPT input to transfer data to and from a cassette player. From what I understand, the interface transforms sinusoidal sound waves into square waves that the ZX Spectrum emulator understands and can load. The interface can also transform square waves back to sinusoidal waves to save programs and data back onto cassette. My current PC has only USB ports. Although I have been able to connect printers with only LPT inputs using an off the shelf USB to LPT port cable, I am wondering, though, if this would work for what I need it to do using the "ykhwong" version of DOSBox.

I hope that this does not sound too much like the ramblings of someone gone mad and that someone among you understands what I'm trying to do and can help me with this. Thank you.